# Word with the same meaning as "good moments" or "pleasant memories"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Is there a single word with the same meaning as "good moments" or "pleasant memories"? I'm looking for a word which describes good thing(s) that happened to someone. The only word I can think of is "joy".

Some examples might be:

- Wayne has many pleasant memories of the days spent with the family.
- She could remember many good moments from the last weekend.

Comment: please can you add a sentence where you would use this word?

Comment: @MattЭллен added examples to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Reminisce* means to talk, think, or write about enjoyable experiences in your past (Macmillan Dictionary) or to indulge in enjoyable recollection of past events (Merriam Webster).

Your example sentences could be reworded:

•Wayne reminisced about the days spent with the family.
•She reminisced about last weekend.

*Reminiscence* would be the noun form. (I did find it interesting that most dictionaries define the verb *reminisce* as an enjoyable act, but the noun *reminiscence* was not necessarily defined as being pleasant or enjoyable.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe *Nostalgia*? As in to *feel nostalgic*?

Wayne *feels nostalgic* of the days spent with the family.

She *felt nostalgic* about last weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be looking for a noun.  (Other answers offer good verbs and adjectives.)

For the second sentence you could use *highlights*:

> She could remember many *highlights* from the last weekend.

You *remember* highlights but I don't think you *have* them, so this doesn't help in your first example.  What's wrong with "pleasant memories"?

Answer (score 1):

*[**Halcyon**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halcyon)*, used as an [adjective](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/halcyon#Adjective):

> a: calm, peaceful
>    b: happy, golden
>    c : prosperous, affluent

Given synonyms include *calm, hushed, lown [dialect], peaceful, placid, quiet, serene, still, stilly, tranquil, untroubled*.

**Edit:**  If you are looking for a noun as Monica suggests, what about

- [delight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delight)

> 1:  a high degree of gratification : joy; also : extreme satisfaction
>   2:  something that gives great pleasure

Examples of *delight*:

- We watched the fireworks with *delight*.
- The kids *screamed in delight* as they chased one another around the
  park.
- *To the delight of the children*, there were enough cookies for
  everyone to have two.
- Some people seem to take great *delight* in hearing about the
  misfortunes of others.
- The trip was *a delight*.
- a garden full of *tasty delights*
- The stories are *a delight to* read.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest noun *[reverie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reverie)* ("state of dreaming while awake: ... castle in the air, [daydream](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/daydream), daydreaming, [oneirism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oneirism)") and noun or verb *[daydream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daydream)* ("a visionary fantasy, especially one of happy, pleasant thoughts, hopes or ambitions").

Wikipedia includes "review of past memories" among things people refer to when they talk about *daydreaming*.  This applies to *reverie* even more, I think, although I don't have a source that says so.  That is, I think *reverie* often connotes recall of pleasant past events.